# app crashes as the late init property has not been initialized in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, kotlin-lateinit

I have a button, when i click on that, it should show the Alert dialog box, But app crashes when i click on that button I know the code flow is this but I dont know Where i had done my mistake

```
      private lateinit var btn: Button
      
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dynam)
        btn = findViewById(R.id.add1)
        buildDialog()

        btn.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
              dialog.show()
            }
        })
    }

    private fun buildDialog() {
        val builder=android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_dynam,null)
      val name=  view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameEdit)
        builder.setView(view)
        builder.setTitle("Enter name")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",object :DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, p1: Int) {
addname(name.text.toString())

                }`
```

Comment: Post the full stacktrace of the error

Comment: I'm guessing `dialog` is a `lateinit` property that you forgot to assign in `buildDialog()`.

Comment: yeah @Tenfour04 I think I had added though, since my line is                                   lateinit var dialog: AlertDialog

Comment: And where did you put `dialog =`? It should be at the end of your `buildDialog()` function.

Comment: I couldn't get you. why should i place the dialog there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have `dialog` as a `lateinit` variable and you forgot to  assign it in `buildDialog` function.

```
      private lateinit var btn: Button
      private lateinit var dialog:AlertDialog

      
      override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dynam)
        btn = findViewById(R.id.add1)
        buildDialog()

        btn.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
         if (this@YourActivity::dialog.isInitialized) { // to check if dialog is initialize or not
          dialog.show()
         }
            
            }
        })
    }

    private fun buildDialog() {
        val builder=android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        val view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_dynam,null)
        val name=  view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.nameEdit)
        builder.setView(view)
        builder.setTitle("Enter name")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok",object :DialogInterface.OnClickListener{
                override fun onClick(dialog: DialogInterface?, p1: Int) {
                addname(name.text.toString())

        // initialize dialog
        dialog = builder.create()
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort But i couldn't get my word "dialog" inside the if statement combined with  "this::"

Comment: that is used as a safety factor to check if lateinit variable dialog is initialized or not.

Comment: yeah i saw in some suggestions , but i couldn't access my variable "dialog" inside that "if statement"

Comment: Suppose you are doing this in MainActivity, the try using "this@MainActivity::dialog.isInitialized" in if statement.

Comment: Yeah done .. it doesn't crashes but i din't get my dialog box after clicking the button ..LOL

Comment: check if you have initialize dialog in buildDialog() method.

Comment: I will solve then for my dialog. Thanks for your Time.